# How can I properly notate an operation on all items of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Say I have two sets of arbitrary numbers, A and B. How do I notate, for example, multiplying each member of ${A_i}$ by ${B_i}$, to produce set C with each member, $C_i$ equal to ${A_i*B_i}$(not cartesian product). E.g $C\in\{a_1*b_1, a_2*b_2, ..., a_i*b_i\}$.

At first I thought sigma would demonstrate the idea, however at second thought I believe ${\sum A_i*B_i }$ would not imply my intentions per se, rather that I was adding the product of each pair to single value C.

So how exactly would be the best way to go about notating this? Note that taking the product was just an example, I am looking for a general method.

Comment: I gather you have a pair of functions $a:I\to A$, $b:I\to B$ and you want the point-wise product $a*b:I\to C$, as opposed to having an operation that depends exclusively on the sets $A$ and $B$ as you would seem to imply.

Comment: I will point out that the set $\{1,2,3\}$ is equal to to the set $\{3,2,1\}$.  So, unless you clarify that you are talking about ordered sets it is ambiguous whether when applying this proposed operation between the sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{a,b,c\}$ you would get $\{1a,2b,3c\}$ or if you would get $\{3a,2b,1c\}$ or some other permutation.

Comment: If you were to talk about your objects as matrices or vectors or similar, then you could describe this as a [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), here unambiguously being $[1,2,3]\circ [a,b,c] = [1a,2b,3c]$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of a ring (some algebraic structure with a multiplication such as the set of integers), then
$$A \cdot B = \{a\cdot b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$$
is the socalled complex product of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The OP seems to be looking at ordered sets and is only taking the diagonal products $a_i \cdot b_i$, not all products $a_i \cdot b_j$.